# Scene Builder not reconazing my Controller class

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm trying a simple project in JAVAFX using Intelij Idea, so i have 2 cases of problems:

case 1 :

When i put `sample.fxml` and `controller.java` and `main.java` in the same folder `src/main/java/FX/` :

1- SceneBuilder find controller.java

2- Main.java not find the FXML file

[image]

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/FX/sample.fxml"));

/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_20/bin/java -Didea.launcher.port=7537 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=/opt/idea-IU-143.381.42/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /opt/java/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/jce.jar:/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/resources.jar:/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/rt.jar:/home/azb/IdeaProjects/TestMavenFX/target/classes:/opt/idea-IU-143.381.42/lib/idea_rt.jar com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain FX.Main

** (java:7837): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-MBNrjIF7ES: Connection refused
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:875)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$147(LauncherImpl.java:157)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$1/424058530.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3201)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3169)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3142)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3118)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3098)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3091)
    at FX.Main.start(Main.java:13)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$153(LauncherImpl.java:821)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$55/669200515.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(PlatformImpl.java:323)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$51/645218408.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(PlatformImpl.java:292)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$53/222734631.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(PlatformImpl.java:291)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$52/444279218.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$45(GtkApplication.java:126)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication$$Lambda$43/1060865646.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

case 2 :

When i put `sample.fxml` in the folder `src/main/resources/FX/`  and `controller.java` and `main.java` in the folder `src/main/java/FX/` :

1- SceneBuilder not find controller.java

2- Main.java find the FXML file, and the program run

[image]

Question : where's the wrong with this two cases ? witch cas is suppose to be the good one ? please help

Thanks

Comment: Usually you need to define your controller class in the fxml file

Answer (score 2):

Define your controller class in your fxml file :

```
<AnchorPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" id="GridPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" styleClass="mainFxmlClass" fx:controller="yourpackage.yourControllerClass">
   <children>
     ...
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: I tried it it didn't work ...it will show up in the controller field in the scenebuilder ...but it won't show the methods inside my class,that's mean it didn't detect my Java controller class .

Answer (score 2):

According to this answer the only is to put in the same folder where your **FXML** file exist,the problem is from **scenebuilder** it has a limitation .

chekc out the link below for more details

[SceneBuilder 2: Do controller classes need to necessarily be in the same folder as the view FXML files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28830132/scenebuilder-2-do-controller-classes-need-to-necessarily-be-in-the-same-folder)

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. Have been fighting with it for 4 hours in a row!

Comment: Glad to know that .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Firstly I wrote my controller class on the fxml file manually, after that annotated @FXML at the top of the each method on the controller class than figured it out.